# Simple Form Processing API for Java

Tags: java, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, bean-validation

I'm looking for a very simple form processing API for Java. Assuming the form input fields correspond to bean properties, and all beans have javax.Validation annotations, ideally the API would:

- Display a bean as an html form
- Populate the bean, including nested objects where applicable, using the request parameters
- Validate the input using Validation annotation
- If there is an error, display errors at top of form, and highlight error fields.

Additionally:

- It would be nice if i didn't have to buy into a whole application framework, since I am working with a legacy app.
- Allow configuration for more complicated use cases, but by default just use convention.

Bonus:

- generates javascript client side validation too.

Note: If this requires several different libraries, that is fine too.

**Update:**

Since I never found what I was looking for, and migrating to Spring was not an option, I went ahead and rolled my own solution. It is, affectionately, called [java in jails](http://petercowan.com/jjails) (loosely modeled on rails form processing). It gives you dead simple (and pretty) form creation, client and server side validation, and request parameter to object mapping. No configuration required.

Example Bean:

```
public class AccountForm {
    @NotBlank(groups = RequiredChecks.class)
    @Size(min = 2, max = 25)
    private String name;
//...
}
```

Example Form:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://org.jails.org/form/taglib" prefix="s" %>
<s:form name="accountForm" action="/jails-demo/jails" label="Your Account Details" style="side">
    <s:text name="name" label="Name" size="25" />
    <s:text name="accountName" label="Account Name" size="15" />
    ...
</s:form>
```

Example Validation and Mapping:

```
SimpleValidator validator = new SimpleValidator();

if ("submit".equals(request.getParameter("submit"))) {
    Map<String, List<String>> errors = validator.validate(AccountForm.class, request.getParameterMap());

    if (errors != null) {
        AccountForm account = validator.getMapper().toObject(AccountForm.class, request.getParameterMap());
        //do something with valid account
    } else {
        SimpleForm.validateAs(AccountForm.class).inRequest(request).setErrors(errors);
        //handle error
    }
} else {
    SimpleForm.validateAs(AccountForm.class).inRequest(request);
    //forward to formPage
}
```

This is what the form looks like, with client side validation using jQuery (provided by [Position Absolute](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)):

[image]

Comment: we usually do not provide complete solutions like you have asked above. Why don't you start developing your "form" and then when you have more specific coding questions we can help you more?

Comment: Thanks for the offer... I actually wasn't looking for coding help, I was looking for a n existing solution that I could just plug into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will find something that has most of this functionality and is not a framework.

I can recommend Spring MVC - you can plug it in easily in the legacy app. It supports all of the above.

Doing-it-yourself won't be that hard either:

- use `BeanUtils.populate(bean, request.getParameterMap())` to fill your object with the request parameters
- use `javax.validation.*` manually - [here is how](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/Validation.html). For each error add request attributes which you can later display as errors.

Note that either way you will have to write the html code manually.

Comment: BeanUtils.populate(bean, request.getParameterMap())... that's half the battle. does it come with stock converters for String->Primitive->String or do yu have to write your own? unfortunately, writing the HTML was what the other thing I was most interested in trying to get around not having to do myself!

Comment: scatch that. i see that there are stock converters for all the standard use cases, and you can create your own as needed. thanks again!